# During MSSQL secure connection facing error: 0x8009030d. Check certificates to make sure they are valid

Tags: sql-server, security, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a secure connection for my SQL server using certificate. I have generated CA certificate and used it to sign the subordinate certificate using XCA tool.

Installed the certificate in Local computer "Personal" store and CA in "Trusted Root Authorities" store. Also added the SQL server user in the "Manage Private Keys -> Security" option and given permission to SQL user for the "MSSQL" installation folder.

I could able to see the certificate in "SQl Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration" and added the certificate. Set "Force Encryption" option as YES.

Now when i restart the SQL server, getting the following error:

> The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL
> connection. It returned the following error: 0x8009030d. Check
> certificates to make sure they are valid.
>
> Starting up database 'model'.
>
> Server name is 'VCE-W0031'. This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required.
>
> Error: 26014, Severity: 16, State: 1. Unable to load user-specified
> certificate [Cert Hash(sha1) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"].
> The server will not accept a connection. You should verify that the
> certificate is correctly installed. See "Configuring Certificate for
> Use by SSL" in Books Online.
>
> Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code
> 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. Cannot find object or
> property.
>
> Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>
> TDSSNIClient initialization
> failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization
> failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. Cannot
> find object or property.
>
> Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
>
> Could not start the network
> library because of an internal error in the network library. To
> determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one
> in the error log.

I have created another CA and certificate using Openssl tool and insalled in Trusted Authorities and Personal stores respectively. Added this certificate in
"SQl Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration" and added the certificate. Set "Force Encryption" option as YES.

Without any further setting, i could able to run the SQL server and the encrypted connection is established when client is connected.

Please let me know why this error could happen in case of certificate generated using XCA, but not Openssl.

The question what i wanted to ask is, using a certificate which is signed by an existing certification authority instead of creating a CA with openssl could cause any issue?

Comment: You seem to spend a lot of time here going through the steps of using your certificates (which is identical between the two tools), but just gloss over the creation steps. Since it's highly likely the difference is in how you used the two tools, that's likely to be the most important place to focus on.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Are there any check points i can look at in case of this error? Either in generating the certificate or permission related points.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue: copied a personal certificate between two hives. The certificate was usable, but after reboot services failed to use it with this error: SEC_E_UNKNOWN_CREDENTIALS (0x8009030D).

Resolved by starting the Protected Storage Service and re-importing the certificate directly into the computer personal hive.

Comment: In windows server 2008, Protected Storage Service is read only. It is already deprecated by Microsoft. Could you please explain how you have started this?

Comment: Thought this would help. Sorry... this worked out with Windows Server 2003 and WinXP machines.